# Find substring inside of string with various possible whitespaces

Tags: php, regex

I have a region called "`PADERNE ABF`" from a Zipcode database and I need it to match against a piece of HTML like this

```
<option value="33425">PADERNE(ALBUFEIRA)</option>
```

So if any strings match the first word (that's not in parentheses) and disregarding any whitespace, then I should have a match.
How can I achieve this with a PHP RegEx?

Comment: So you want to get `PADERNE ABF` from `<option value="33425">PADERNE ABF(ALBUFEIRA)</option>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(<)(option)( )(value)(=)(".*?")(>)(PADERNE)(\\(.*\\))(<\\/option>)
```

This regex matches any string in the format:

```
<option value="ANYTHING">PADERNE(ANYTHING)</option>
```

---

```
  $txt='<option value="33425">PADERNE(ALBUFEIRA)</option>';  

  $re1='(<)';   
  $re2='(option)';  
  $re3='( )';   
  $re4='(value)';   
  $re5='(=)';   
  $re6='(".*?")';   
  $re7='(>)';   
  $re8='(PADERNE)'; 
  $re9='(\\(.*\\))';    
  $re10='(<\\/option>)';

  if ($c=preg_match_all ("/".$re1.$re2.$re3.$re4.$re5.$re6.$re7.$re8.$re9.$re10."/is", $txt, $matches))
  {
      $c1=$matches[1][0];
      $word1=$matches[2][0];
      $ws1=$matches[3][0];
      $word2=$matches[4][0];
      $c2=$matches[5][0];
      $string1=$matches[6][0];
      $c3=$matches[7][0];
      $word3=$matches[8][0];
      $rbraces1=$matches[9][0];
      $tag1=$matches[10][0];
      print "($c1) ($word1) ($ws1) ($word2) ($c2) ($string1) ($c3) ($word3) ($rbraces1) ($tag1) \n";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to split up the city you got and take only the first word to search for in the HTML. It will then print out the name between the option tag.

```
<?
$city = 'PADERNE ABF';
$search = explode(' ', $city);
$search = $search[0];
$html = '<option value="33425">PADERNE(ALBUFEIRA)</option>';
preg_match('/>('.$search.'.*?)</i', $html, $m);
print_r($m[1]);
```